# Request status using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to get the request/response status of a post form using JavaScript?.

Actually I'm uploading a file and I need to know if it's already saved; Target property pointing to an `<iframe>` became a good choice, but also I'm appending a JQuery event in order to refresh a list of files outside the `<iframe>`; is it possible to catch the status or the response? Any Ideas of how could I solve this problem?

Comment: You'll have to show how you are doing POST requests with JS.  Are you using jQuery, native `XMLHttpRequest()`, etc.?  Also it's totally possible to capture the response.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica he's posting to an iframe.

Comment: Yes, bind to the load event of the iframe. When it loads, inspect it's contents to get the response.

Comment: You can grab the response payload if you are posting to an iframe, but certainly not the status or any headers associated with the response.

Comment: @KevinB Didn't have code there when I commented.

Comment: And just to clarify, we need to see your actual code for what you're trying.  POST'ing to an `iframe` definitely complicates things.  Why not just POST to a URL?

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica I think there is a concept here you are not familiar with.  It is common to submit a form containing one or more file inputs and then target an iframe when supporting file uploads in older browsers.  Targeting an iframe allows multiple uploads to occur simultaneously, among other benefits.  Again, this is done in older browsers that do not support uploading files via ajax.

Comment: @RayNicholus Ahh I didn't realize that was the way older browsers had to handle multiple file uploads, I apologize.